# first_name user property is not logged, is it reserved in firebase analytics?

Tags: android, firebase, properties, firebase-analytics

I integrated firebase analytics in my app. Have set some User Properties too. I have registered those properties in console and it works fine but except for now property. Name of that beautiful property is first_name. :).

I don't find it in [Automatically collected user properties](https://support.google.com/firebase/answer/6317486).

I can't see first_name property logged in 'Debug View'. I see all properties I added along with them though.

Any clues ?

Comment: `first_name` is not one of the [documented reserved user property names](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/analytics/FirebaseAnalytics.UserProperty)

Comment: yeah, any clue why it is not logged then?

Comment: Have you exceeded the limit of 25?

Comment: Thanks for quick response. No, I have only 5 User Props added in console.

Comment: This isn't much help, but I just tried reporting `first_name`.  Got this in the logcat: `D/FA: Setting user property (FE): first_name, Bob` and see the user property in the DebugView.  This is with Firebase 11.6.0.

Comment: I can see it as well in my logs on terminal: "/FA-SVC  ( 6493): User property set: first_name, Guru.". But I don't see it in Debug View. Well, I have 11.0.1 integrated. Not sure if that makes any difference. I can try out that.

Comment: @BobSnyder tried with 11.6.0, the latest. It does not work yet. The same code it works for another property, "debug_first_name" in this code:
firebaseAnalytics.setUserProperty(“first_name”, getFirstName());  firebaseAnalytics.setUserProperty("debug_first_name", getFirstName());

Comment: Thanks for help @BobSnyder. It seem to be working. It does not show up in Debug View, not sure why though, but in Events section I could find it.

Answer (score 2):

It did not require any fix but just that it was not logged in Debug View for some reason. But I could see it in Events. Click on Events on on left pane -> Add Filter -> User Property -> first_name.

Comment: That may be because someone already registered User Property in Firebase dashboard